# Display the hour

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm tryring to write an algo with JS that displays the time with the h/m/s format, counting seconds per seconds and with a H24 format.
The goal is to obtain the time one second after having defined the time.

Link here : https://repl.it/@LunaShivaya/Heure-suivante

Problem on "unexpected token" in line 6.

Comment: use ``>= ``, ``=>`` is arrow function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=>` defines an arrow function so `=>` should be `>=`

`if (secondes < 0 || secondes >= 60 || minutes < 0 || minutes >= 60 || heures < 0 || heures > 23) {...}`

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone.
I was persuaded that my operator was correct. xD

Happy to see it is working. ^^

Answer (score 0):

You have mispalced `=` when checking greater than equals. it should be `>=`.

```js
let heures = 26; // Faire varier cette variable entre 0 et 23
let minutes = 17; // faire varier cette variable entre 0 et 59
let secondes = 59; // faire varier cette variable entre 0 et 59

// Ajoutez votre code ici
if (secondes < 0 || secondes >= 60 || minutes < 0 || minutes >= 60 || heures < 0 || heures > 23) {
  console.log("Impossible!");
}
else if (secondes == 59 && minutes == 59 && heures == 23) {
  secondes = 0;
  minutes = 0;
  heures = 0;
  console.log(heures + "h" + minutes + "m" + secondes + "s");
}
else if (secondes == 59 && minutes == 59 && 0 <= heures <= 22) {
  secondes = 0;
  minutes = 0;
  heures += 1;
  console.log(heures + "h" + minutes + "m" + secondes + "s");
}
else if (secondes = 59 && 0 <= minutes <= 58) {
  secondes = 0;
  minutes += 1;
  console.log(heures + "h" + minutes + "m" + secondes + "s");
} 
else if (0 <= secondes <= 58) {
  secondes += 1;
  console.log(heures + "h" + minutes + "m" + secondes + "s");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should replace `=>` with `>=`